# Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: IdAllocation state is probably corrupted or out of sync with the cluster

Tags: neo4j

I try to create node in the graph.db and get this error:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: IdAllocation state is probably corrupted or out of sync with the cluster. Local highId is 573057 and allocation range is IdRange[32768-33791, defrag []]
```

My DB was migrated from Neo4j Community Edition (neo4j-community-3.0.6) to Enterprise (neo4j-enterprise-3.2.3) by copying binaries and upgrading it.  Then I configured Causal Cluster.

Here is log from debug.log:

```
2018-04-12 07:11:43.870+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.r.ErrorReporter] Client triggered an unexpected error [UnknownError]: IdAllocation state is probably corrupted or out of sync with the cluster. Local highId is 573057 and allocation range is IdRange[15360-16383, defrag []], reference 2ca1aca3-3a60-441c-9fe1-dbd431ae400a. IdAllocation state is probably corrupted or out of sync with the cluster. Local highId is 573057 and allocation range is IdRange[15360-16383, defrag []]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: IdAllocation state is probably corrupted or out of sync with the cluster. Local highId is 573057 and allocation range is IdRange[15360-16383, defrag []]
        at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.machines.id.ReplicatedIdGenerator.respectingHighId(ReplicatedIdGenerator.java:210)
        at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.machines.id.ReplicatedIdGenerator.storeLocally(ReplicatedIdGenerator.java:194)
        at org.neo4j.causalclustering.core.state.machines.id.ReplicatedIdGenerator.nextId(ReplicatedIdGenerator.java:126)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.id.IdGenerator$Delegate.nextId(IdGenerator.java:62)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.nextId(CommonAbstractStore.java:571)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.PropertyCreator.primitiveSetProperty(PropertyCreator.java:140)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.TransactionRecordState.nodeAddProperty(TransactionRecordState.java:418)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.TransactionToRecordStateVisitor.visitNodePropertyChanges(TransactionToRecordStateVisitor.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.storageengine.api.txstate.TxStateVisitor$Delegator.visitNodePropertyChanges(TxStateVisitor.java:205)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.TxState$14.visitPropertyChanges(TxState.java:405)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.PropertyContainerStateImpl.accept(PropertyContainerStateImpl.java:214)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.NodeStateImpl.accept(NodeStateImpl.java:152)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.TxState.accept(TxState.java:245)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.createCommands(RecordStorageEngine.java:303)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.commit(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:553)
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the query you ran? What did the graph look like beforehand? 
And, probably the most important, were you able to use the database after upgrading but before enabling clustering?

Finally, it's not clear to me whether all instances in the cluster are on the same version. Are they?

Comment: My query like this:

MERGE (user:User{userId:123123123}) ON CREATE SET user = { userId:123123123, userName:null };

I didn't check DB on stanalone enterprise instance, I checked it on the Cluster and I was able to run match() queries.

All instances run the same version neo4j-enterprise-3.2.3.

Comment: If you bring down the additional nodes and keep only the leader node, then bring that one down and reconfigure it to be a single instance before bringing back up, are you able to then use it normally?

Comment: I found the root cause of my issue.
At first time I configured Causal Cluster and started it with default graph.db. Then I deleted default DB and put binaries from my Community Edition instance. In the single mode instance I upgraded DB and transferred to each member of cluster.

The problem begins at the moment when I started cluster at first time. Neo4j created cluster-state in the ./data/cluster-state/*. So my upgraded DB didn't work, because cluster uses stored states of the original graph.db, not mine. So I cleared cluster-state and my DB works properly.
Thanks, Rebeca.

Comment: Just to add to @Alex's point, we need to shut down neo4j on all clusters first and then delete the contents from `./data/cluster-state/*` Once it's deleted from all clusters, then we can restart neo4j on them, and then it works. As in my case, in my first attempt I didn't shut down neo4j on all clusters, did one by one, in that case it didn't work. So just a heads up!